# Creating and installing apps on Hololens without Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I tried the examples given on this tutorial and it works fine: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_240.

After I build the examples using Unity the output is a folder with 2.16 GB size and it is a visual studio project (.sln file). I think the output will be a single file (like apk for Android).

What I need is how to create a Hololens application file from the this Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this explains what you are after.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

For Unity/Hololens, you need to build without C# debugging, then in VS, select Master and x86 and disable ARM and X64 when creating the package.

But I can't confirm this applies to Hololens.

Comment: This works fine. But I need to know if there is a way to do this without visual studio

Comment: I don't think so. Just like iOS needs xcode. Actually, you cant,for now, use cloud build for hololens either. So no, you have to go through VS.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my tutorial which includes information on how to build and deploy to the emulator or HoloLens:

http://www.cameronvetter.com/2016/10/25/hololens-tutorial-unity-3d-project-creation/

Specifically you should follow these instructions, (but the entire tutorial is likely to be useful for you):

> Deploy to HoloLens
>
> In the VS toolbar set the Solution Configuration to
>   Release and the Solution Platform to x86.  For Build Target select
>   Remote Device.  You will see this configuration screen:
>
> If everything goes well you will see your HoloLens listed as Auto
>   Detected.  Simply select it.  If not on your HoloLens say “Hey
>   Cortana, What is my IP Address” and enter the address, leaving
>   authentication mode set to Universal.  Click Debug, Start Debugging. 
>   Your project will build and deploy to the HoloLens, you should see a
>   Unity Logo, followed by nothing because we have not implemented
>   anything.  Press Stop in Visual Studio closing the application on your
>   HoloLens.
>
> Deploy to Emulator
>
> In the VS toolbar set the Solution Configuration to
>   Release and the Solution Platform to x86.  For Build Target select
>   HoloLens Emulator.  Click Debug, Start Debugging.  Your project will
>   build and deploy to the HoloLens Emulator, you should see a Unity
>   Logo, followed by nothing because we have not implemented anything. 
>   Press Stop in Visual Studio closing the application on the Emulator. 
>   To learn more about the emulator visit the Hololens Emulator
>   reference.